# updating view automatically using Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-observable

I use observable and HTTP request to add data on server then update other route .

I would that data get updated instantly. Actually I should refresh page to get new data

In my service I use `AddProj()` and `getAllProj()` functions to get and send data

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NouveauProjet } from "./models/nouveau-projet";
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";

@Injectable()
export class AjoutprojService {
  apiURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/proj/projets";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllProj(): Observable<NouveauProjet[]> {
    return this.http.get<NouveauProjet[]>(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/projets"
    );
  }
  addProj(nouveauProjet: NouveauProjet): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<NouveauProjet[]>(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/proj/projets",
    nouveauProjet
  );
}
}
```

in **ajoutproj.ts** I put data with `addProjet()`

```
addProjet() {
  this.nouveauProjet = {
    ...this.firstFormGroup.value,
    ...this.secondFormGroup.value,
    ...this.thirdFormGroup.value
  };
  this.ajoutProj
    .addProj(this.nouveauProjet)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.message);
    });
}
```

in my **listprojects.ts** file I get data using `getAllProj()`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
import { AjoutprojService } from "../ajoutproj.service";
import { NouveauProjet } from "../models/nouveau-projet";

@Component({
  selector: "app-liste-projets",
  templateUrl: "./liste-projets.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./liste-projets.component.css"]
})
export class ListeProjetsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ajoutProj: AjoutprojService) {}
  nouveauProjet: NouveauProjet[];
  stateExression: string = "inactive";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProj();
  }
  displayedColumns = ["Nom projet", "Lead Projet", "effectif"];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<NouveauProjet>(this.nouveauProjet);

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  getAllProj() {
    this.ajoutProj.getAllProj().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<NouveauProjet>(response);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

}
```

**Update** I add my template:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Nom projet">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nom projet </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let nouveauProjet"> {{nouveauProjet.nomProj }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Lead Projet">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Lead Projet </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let nouveauProjet"> {{nouveauProjet.leadProj }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="effectif">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> effectif </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let nouveauProjet"> {{nouveauProjet.pers.length }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>



    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

**Update 2** : I have made a stackblitz [repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dynamicform) , I can't reproduce server side , juste Front side

I don't have error but my problem is that data don't get updated automatically . I should refresh my page every time to get new changes knowing that I'm using Obersables. what did I forget ?

Comment: Could you also show the metadata for your `@Component`? In your case, I think it's `ListeProjetsComponent`. You might have the `OnPush` change detection strategy enabled.

Comment: I haven't used OnPush I don't know what does make

Comment: The `changeDetection` is a property for the metadata object of the component. Long story short, it changes the way Angular will listen for changes in your component. This is very useful for performance increase.

You can read [https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#change-detection here] for more information about change detection in Angular.

If you haven't used it, then perhaps you should also update the question with your template so we can see what happens there.

Comment: The data that should be changed is `dataSource` and it's binded to the `mat-table` component?

Comment: yes mat-table uses dataSource variable.  I'm using the table component of the Angular Material library https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I can't see anything wrong at the first glance. Other things that might go wrong are: the `dataSource` object is bound to `mat-table` and when you update it, the reference doesn't change which leads to `mat-table` not re-rendering itself OR simply a small mistake that needs some debugging. I suggest you reproduce this issue in a jsfiddle or something similar, or make a repository to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For subscribes an Obersables and returns the latest value it has emitted,you can try to use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

Comment: How can I use it in my sourcedata variable ?

Comment: Add pipe async in your template variables : {{ variable  | async }}

Comment: I get an error : `InvalidPipeArgument: 'value' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' `

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted Material Data Tables' datasource: Data<T> to be an Observable.
you will find an example with "connect(): Observable" here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-table?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks for the exemple , It's a little bit hard to adapt it to my example, feel free to change my stackblitz repo